# Having trouble with CSS3 search box

Tags: html, css, search

I'm using this precoded css3 search box but it isn't working for me.

The CSS:

```
.cf:before, .cf:after{ 
.cf:after{
    clear:both;
}

.cf{
    zoom:1;
} 

/* Form wrapper styling */
.form-wrapper {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin:50px auto;
    background:rgb(7,131,71);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

/* Form text input */

.form-wrapper input {
    width: 330px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;   
    font: bold 15px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;     
}

.form-wrapper input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8) inset;
}

.form-wrapper input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: rgb(7,131,71);
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: rgb(7,131,71);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

.form-wrapper input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: rgb(7,131,71);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}   

/* Form submit button */
.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    font: bold 15px/40px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: rgb(7,131,71);
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;     
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
}  

.form-wrapper button:hover{    
    background: #3A423B;
}  

.form-wrapper button:active,
.form-wrapper button:focus{  
    background: rgb(7,131,71);
    outline: 0;  
}

.form-wrapper button:before { /* left arrow */
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent rgb(7,131,71) transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}

.form-wrapper button:hover:before{
    border-right-color: #3A423B;
}

.form-wrapper button:focus:before,
.form-wrapper button:active:before{
        border-right-color: rgb(7,131,71);
}     

.form-wrapper button::-moz-focus-inner { /* remove extra button spacing for Mozilla Firefox */
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
<form method="get" action="https://encrypted.google.com/search" target="_top">
        <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search here..." required>
        <button type="submit">Charge!</button>
    </form>
```

Everything seems to work fine except when I click "Charge!" (the submit button). Nothing happens. It doesn't search through google like it's supposed to. Help?

Comment: Please mark questions as "solved" by clicking the green tick by an answer (and perhaps giving it and other good answers up votes). Don't put the word "solved" in the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two form tags. You need to close your input tag. I don't know what `required` is for, but this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/t743qqxo/

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" method="get" action="https://encrypted.google.com/search" target="_top">
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search here..." required />
    <button type="submit">Charge!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: required is probably jquery val

Comment: required is HTML5. It's saying put a placeholder in the search bar like "Enter your Search terms here" and required is telling the browser that the user can not submit the search terms without actually putting something in the search bar.